# Specify name of ZIP file created by AppVeyor

Tags: appveyor

AFAICT I can tell AppVeyor to wrap an entire folder into a zip file artifact, as in the following example:

```
artifacts:
  - path: logs
    name: test logs
    type: zip
```

which will push all the files in the `logs` subfolder to the `logs.zip` ZIP file.

I want to give the generated ZIP file a different name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `name` attribute controls the name of the ZIP file as well. So if I want the ZIP file to be named `foo.zip`, I can write the following in the `appveyor.yml`:

```
artifacts:
  - path: logs
    name: foo
    type: zip
```

And so I've done -- see [here](https://github.com/zspitz/ANTLR4ParseTreeVisualizer/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L48) and [here](https://github.com/zspitz/ANTLR4ParseTreeVisualizer/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L66).

Answer (score 3):

Issue number [929 in the community support repository](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/929) suggests that this is currently not supported declaratively. What you **can** do is rename the artifact in the `after_build` step as outlined in the issue:

> ```
> after_build:
> - appveyor PushArtifact local-file.zip -FileName remote-file-%appveyor_build_version%.zip
> ```